# 2d arrays and their relation to a pointer to pointer

Tags: c++

I am new to the  forum,(although I passionately wassearching foransweres here during the last 2 years) and also kind of new to the topics of c++. My question is about a much-discussed topic: Why a pointer to pointer is not equivallent during compilation to a 2d array. I ve made a lot of search and I know that an intermediate step of declaring an array of pointers is needed. But still, I am not getting what is the inner process that is happening in the compilation that creates the error. I mean lets say:
int a[3][2];
int **p;
How the complier evaluates the command:
a
(what produces when facing the name of the matrix without inidices) and why can not assign it to p?

At the end of the day the 2d array decays into a pointer to pointer(even if an intermediate step is missing) Thank you and i hope i was annoying, looking for a more thorough answere to a trivial topic.

Answer (score 0):

> At the end of the day the 2d array decays into a pointer to pointer

No, they don't. Array-to-pointer decay only happens exactly once; a `T[n]` decays to a `T*`.

In the case of 2D arrays, a `T[n][m]` decays to a `T(*)[m]`.

Here is an example where an `int[5][10]` decays to an `int(*)[10]`:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but if int(*p)[10] is an array of pointers, each of them showing to one row of the matrix, shouldn't then be int(*p)[5], instead of int(*p)[10]?

Comment: `int(*p)[10]` is *not* an array of pointers, but a pointer to an array; `p` points to `a[0]`, which is of type `int[10]`.

Comment: yeah, figured it out, thanx!